# simple news confirmation message

Tags: 7, emails

i am using simplenews module in drupal7 . i mentioned simplenews block on home page.
 when i enter email id it shows message "You will receive a confirmation e-mail shortly containing further instructions on how to complete your subscription." on home page . now i need to show this message on  new page(not on home page). 
also i want to change the text of that message

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the subscription confirmation pages at: /admin/config/services/simplenews/settings/subscription > "Confirmation pages"

> SUBSCRIBE CONFIRMATION
>
> Drupal path or URL of the destination page where after the
>   subscription is confirmed (e.g. node/123). Leave empty to go to the
>   front page.

It may be that that page is only used when confirming from the email link, but might work for the subscribe block as well.

The message text could be overridden with the [stringoverrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module